# My class cannot be cast to android.app.Activity, how to solve this?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-fragmentactivity

In my `MapActivity` class, I set a button and that button needs to go back to a different class, can't seem to get `setOnClickListener` to work in `FragmentActivity`. Here's my code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    Button Live;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        Live=  findViewById(R.id.GoToLive);   
        Live.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorldTabBar.class);
                startActivity(startIntent);            
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I click on a button inside MapActivity, the app crashes and I receive the following error in Android Monitor:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.marcuscarso.appstuff/com.example.marcuscarso.appstuff.WorldTabBar}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.marcuscarso.appstuff.WorldTabBar cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

It extends `Fragment` you need to use `OnCreateView` and set a rootView. But in extends `FragmentActivity` it doesn't work. In `FragmentActivity` error when using `onCreateView` and `savedInstanceState` = "never used"

I've seen solutions that worked for some people with `setOnClickListener` here on StackOverflow but I'm asking now because those solutions didn't work for me. So am I getting this error and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: you need to cast "Live"  to a button like this   `Live= (Button)  findViewById(R.id.GoToLive);`  :: Please try to use Java naming convention small letter first for an object.

Comment: Casting findViewById(R.id.GoToLive) to button is redundant.

Comment: @Barns52 you don't have to cast if compileSdkVersion is >= 26

Comment: I guess I missed reading that this was for a API > 26 in the original post!

Comment: @iBEK How do you know that its not working ?

Comment: Not sure what the compileSDK is but my min=21 and target=26

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi, I tried the OnCreateView and I keep getting errors that OnCreateView is "never used" along with savedInstanceBundle also "never used".

Comment: You don't have to overrride onCreateView. FragmentActivity is subclass of Activity so just think of it as an activity which can support fragments.

Comment: No need to use the application context, use this instead: `Intent startIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, WorldTabBar.class);`

Comment: Does WorldTabBar is sub-class of Activity?

Comment: make sure that WorldTab is subclass of activity and it is mentioned in manifest also.